# Translation or permutation operator on a kronecker product

Tags: operators, quantum-information, linear-algebra

Let's say that I have an initial state given by { $| i_1\rangle \otimes | i_2 \rangle \otimes  \dots \otimes | i_l \rangle $} can I find an operator $\mathbb{T}$ that shifts the state such that:

$\mathbb{T} (|i_1\rangle \otimes | i_2 \rangle \otimes  \dots \otimes | i_l \rangle) = | i_2 \rangle \otimes  | i_3 \rangle \otimes \dots \otimes | i_l \rangle \otimes | i_1 \rangle $

And what's the general form of this operator?

I'm trying to implement this in a small simulation. for my case the states $ |i_i \rangle $ are qudits states so they're represented by $d \times d$ matrices.

Comment: Construct the standard basis of your space, find how your operator acts on it, and find the unique linear operator that does this. If you're doing simulations, you might have a look at software specific ways of solving this problem, such as the permute command in qutip.

Comment: Note that you can write $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{T}_1 \otimes ...  \otimes \mathbb{T}_l$ where $\mathbb{T}_j |i_k \rangle = |i_{k + 1 \ \mathrm{mod} \ l} \rangle$. These $\mathbb{T}_j$, which are all the same, are easy to represent and then you can construct $\mathbb{T}$ by taking tensor products